# Showing lat long instead of numbered index on spatial data map

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

I am trying to project meteorological data from a netcdf4 file with its latitude and longitude information and I am not getting how to show lat-long information on the x and y-axis, in the image instead of index values.

[image]

Here is the code I have written:

```
import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Path of netCDF file
netcdf_fname = "F:\TS\d02_2021-03-31_000000.nc"
# Specify the layer name to read
layer_name = "mcape"
# Open netcdf file.nc with gdal
ds = gdal.Open("NETCDF:{0}:{1}".format(netcdf_fname, layer_name))
# Read full data from netcdf
data = ds.ReadAsArray(0, 0, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize)
data[data < 0] = 0

A = data[4,:,:]
D = plt.imshow(A)
plt.colorbar(D)
plt.title('mcape',fontweight ="bold")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to display the latitude and longitude information in the matplotlib plot. Use extent option in the plt.imshow command to get your desired result.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nc = Dataset(r'D:\Weather data\et_01012017.nc','r')

et = nc.variables['Evapotranspiration'][:]
et_T = np.rot90(et)

lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]

plt.imshow(et_T, extent=[lon.min(), lon.max(), lat.min(),lat.max()])

plt.show()
```

I tried the above code and got the following result:

[image]

Hope this addresses your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, for sharing this method I was able to do by this

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend xarray and/or rioxarray:

```py
import rioxarray

netcdf_fname = "F:\TS\d02_2021-03-31_000000.nc"
# Specify the layer name to read
layer_name = "mcape"
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(netcdf_fname, variable=layer_name)
rds[layer_name].plot()
```

```py
import xarray

netcdf_fname = "F:\TS\d02_2021-03-31_000000.nc"
# Specify the layer name to read
layer_name = "mcape"
rds = xarray.open_dataset(netcdf_fname)
rds[layer_name].plot()
```

Comment: thanks, a lot snowman2 I was able to do by this

Comment: @snowman2. How to list out all the variables/dataset names inside the .nc file using rioxarray if we don't know the dataset/variable/layer names in advance?

Comment: `rds.variables`, `rds.coords`, and `rds.data_vars` are helpful attributes. http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html